# Can I convert a simulink model into a scade model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have to convert a simulink model into a ansys scade model either using python or C. I have zero clue about how to do this, so please let me know.

Comment: SCADE has a Simulink gateway. You just need to have the correct license to do this. It is fairly limited and means that there are certain simulink constructs that aren't supported. Honestly, you are best to use the simulink model as guidance to create your SCADE model rather than trying to convert it.

Comment: As this question looks like it is going to get closed, try contacting SCADE support for help with this.